# How to create this non-regular "identity matrix" with numpy

Tags: numpy

How to create the following matrix, with an input parameter n?

n=2:

```
[[1, 0, 0, 0]
 [0, 0, 0, 1]]
```

n=3:

```
[[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]]
```

n=4:

```
[[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create an all zero array and set desired values to 1:

```
a = np.zeros((n,n*n), dtype=int)
a[np.arange(n),(n+1)*np.arange(n)] = 1
```

Another way is to create a larger *`I(n*n)`* matrix and select every `n+1` rows from it:

```
a = np.eye(n*n, dtype=int)[::n+1]
```

output for `n=4`:

```
[[1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1]]
```

for `n=3`:

```
[[1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1]]
```

And `n=2`:

```
[[1 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 1]]
```

Answer (score 2):

One liner:

```
np.bincount(np.arange(0,n*n*n,n*n+n+1)).reshape(n,n*n)
# array([[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
#        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
#        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
#        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]])
```

With preallocation:

```
out = np.zeros((n,n*n),int)
out.ravel()[::n*n+n+1] = 1
```

or

```
out = np.zeros((n,n*n),int)
np.einsum("iii->i",out.reshape(n,n,n))[...] = 1
```

Comment: @Ehsan I think so, yes. Why?

Comment: Noticed it works and removed comment. Interesting use of einsum. Upvote.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
a = np.zeros(n**3, dtype = int)
a[range(0, n**3, math.ceil(n**3 / (n - 1)) - 1)] = 1
a = a.reshape(n, n**2)
```

Comment: There is a missing parentheses in second line. And I am not sure if this works.